# Content Approval on few columns only

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, flow, content-approval

I have one document library where there is content approval enabled.

I have one MS Flow that is triggered when property of document is modified. (for example someone opened option->approve/Reject the document).

The flow checks that if document is approved then I want to update one column in that document library.

but when my flow update that column the content approval status is changed to "Pending" again.

Can I create exception column that does not update the content approval status.

**Why I am using content approval :**

1. Whenever anybody the changes any important columns the status is immediately changed to "pending" from "approved" (no need of MS Flow/Workflow/Event Receivers)
2. Approve/reject items from list view
3. Multiple item approval with multi-select and approve from option

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of content approval that any modification to the document will change the Approval status to “Pending”.

Currently, it is not supported to create exception column for content approval.

I don’t think this requirement is achievable since Approval status cannot be individually updated as normal columns with Flow. You will have to do a second content approval to update this field.

Reference:

[Require approval of items in a site list or library.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08)